# Missing notifications for watched tags

Tags: support, email, tag-watching, subscriptions

I am watching two tags, but I am not receiving any notifications when new questions include one of these tags. I looked at the options contained in "Edit Email Settings", but I don't see any relevant settings. In particular, the word "tag" doesn't appear anywhere in that section.

How do I receive email notifications due to activity on a watched tag?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Watched tags don't trigger notifications by default. If you want to receive email notifications of new questions with specific tags, you need to create Filters.

Follow these steps:

1. Go to [Filtered Questions](https://stackexchange.com/filters) on stackexchange.com.
2. On the right, click on <kbd>New filter</kbd>. You should see this screen:

   [image: New filter]
3. Select "Just questions tagged with the ... tag" option and enter the tag name.
4. Select "Just these sites" and then select Stack Overflow.
5. Click on <kbd>Add rule</kbd> to create a rule of the selected tag and sites.
6. Repeat steps #3, #4, and #5 to add more rules to your filter.
7. Choose a name for your filter.
8. Tick the "Yes, send to" option, enter your email address, and select the email frequency.
9. Click <kbd>Save Changes</kbd> to save the new filter.

This will add a new subscription to your profile and you should receive a confirmation email.

To manage your subscription list, go to [your profile on the Stack Exchange website](https://stackexchange.com/users/current) and navigate to the "Subscriptions" tab. Alternatively, from your profile on Stack Overflow, you can go to `Edit profile and settings > Edit email settings > Question subscriptions` and then click <kbd>Manage</kbd>.

**Keep in mind that filter subscriptions are [*public*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382966/348196) and anyone can see them on your network profile.**

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks @41686d6564.  I think I was confused by the naming of of the feature "Watch tag".  On GitHub, watching a repository means you receive an email any time there is "activity".  To continue the comparison with GitHub, the behavior of StackOverflow's "Watch tag" feature is like GitHub's feature to "favorite" a repository.  Both features put the tag/repository at the top of lists and in convenient places for me to click on later.

Comment: So what's the point of the "Watched tags" if this feature doesn't trigger anything?

Comment: @PierU it's purpose is to highlight questions on question lists that are in your watched tags. that's... pretty much it. The opposite of your ignored tags.